# why when char data equals object data, Equals() evaluates to false?

Tags: c#, equality

Consider the following snippet:

```
char ch = '[';
string d = "[";

Console.WriteLine(ch.Equals(d))
```

Output will be `false`.

What do you do when you want it to be `true`?

Edit:

variable `d` is a string in the example, but in practice it can be any object...

Comment: Console.WriteLine(ch.ToString().Equals(d));

Comment: Or: `Console.WriteLine(ch.Equals(d[0]));`. Or if `d` could be "anything": `Console.WriteLine(c.Equals(d.ToString()[0]));`

Answer (score 2):

Use `ToString();`

```
var result = '['.ToString().Equals("[");
```

Answer (score 2):

> What do you do when you want it to be true?

Convert your `char` ch to string using `ch.ToString`

```
Console.WriteLine(ch.ToString().Equals(d));
```

Or Convert string to char using `Convert.ToChar`

```
Console.WriteLine(ch.Equals(Convert.ToChar(d)));
```

But the above would fail if your string contains more than one character.

**EDIT:**

> variable d is a string in the example, but in practice it can be any
>   object...

Then it would be better to use [`Convert.ToChar(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/609e20th.aspx) method to convert the object to character and then compare for equality.

```
string d = "[";
char ch = '[';
object o = (object)d;
Console.WriteLine(ch.Equals(Convert.ToChar(o)));
```

The above could throw an exception if the `object` is not convertible to `char`, to be on the safe side you can use [`char.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.tryparse.aspx) like:

```
string d = "[";
char ch = '[';
object obj = (object)d;
char temp;
bool result = obj != null && 
              char.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out temp) && 
              ch == temp; //same as ch.Equals(temp);
```

This would return false, if the conversion to character is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you intend. Either this

```
Console.WriteLine(ch.Equals(d[0]));
```

or that

```
Console.WriteLine(ch.ToString().Equals(d));
```

If `d` could be any object (like you added), you could try to use `d.ToString()` as well. But what sense does it make to compare a `char` to a slider? Depending on the actual type of the object the comparison could become True accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

More generally:

```
char ch = '[';
string d = "[";

bool areEqual = (d != null) && (d.Length == 1) && (d[0].Equals(ch));
```

Assuming you don't want it to be true when comparing null or "[XXX" with '['.